# Extract specific values from a log file

Tags: regex, perl

I want to extract two values on the same line of a log file using Perl.

```
Network             Next Hop               metric    locprf       Path
*|i10.1.5.0/24        10.6.76.242             2        100         0 65000? 
*|i10.1.9.0/24        10.6.76.242           2        100     0 64345 63800?
*|i10.2.9.0/25        10.6.76.242           2        100     0?
```

For each line, I want to extract the network address and the number before the `?`

I have this but it extracts only the network address.

```perl
open( CONF, '<', 'putty-wan.log' ) or die "\n";

my @ip;

open( FICHE, ">RouterNetwork.txt" ) || die ( "Vous ne pouvez pas créer le fichier \"RouterNetwork.txt\"" );

while ( my $line = <CONF> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/\d{1,2})/ ) {
        print FICHE $1, "\n";
    }   
}

close(FICHE);
close CONF;
```

Now I want the regular expression to add or any way to get per line, the network address and the number just before `?`.

Comment: @zdim: She wants the end of the first column. If you look at the regex it has `\/\d{1,2})` at the end.

Comment: @Borodin  Oh, right ... even has the `/` there.  I'm removing that comment, thank you. Here's a replacement then `($ip, $n) = map { s/^\D*|\D$//g; $_ } (split)[0,-1];`

Comment: Or with `/r` (v5.16): `($ip, $n) = map { s/^\D*|\D$//gr } (split)[0,-1]`

Comment: Ok now I read it so i will do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the shown format, you can process the line with

```
my ($ip, $n) = map { s/^\D*|\D*$//gr } (split ' ', $line)[0,-1];
```

or, when the line is in the [`$_` variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$_)

```
my ($ip, $n) = map { s/^\D*|\D*$//gr } (split)[0,-1];
```

With the `/r` *non-desctructive* modifier the new string is returned (leaving the original unchanged, what we don't care about here). It's available since v5.16. If your version of Perl is older use

```
my ($ip, $n) = map { s/^\D*|\D*$//g; $_ } (split)[0,-1];
```

As for processing the whole file, you need a way to detect header lines. How to do this depends on details of your file format. Given the sample, perhaps skip lines starting with letter-only words

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'putty-wan.log';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>)
{
    next if /^[a-zA-Z]+\b/;

    my ($ip, $num) = map { s/^\D*|\D*$//gr } (split)[0,-1];

    say "$ip $num";
}
```

Some comments

- Please *always* start with `use warnings;`, and with `use strict;`
- Use three-argument form of `open`, with a lexical filehandle.  It's better
- Always include `$!` in your `die` statements, to see the actual error. This would be the "default" way to do it while sometimes other [error variables](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) are needed as well.
- While there is nothing wrong with using `||` as you do, the `or` is very handy for flow control, having a suitably lower [precedence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity).  But above all, it's good to be consistent in any case.

---

It's been clarified that the last part on the line can also be `6500 ?` or `65000 i` or such.

Then store all fields in an array and process it from the back, looking for the first field with numbers.

```
while (<$fh>) 
{
    next if /^[a-zA-Z]+\b/;
    my @fields = split;

    my $ip = (shift @fields) =~ s/^\D*//gr;  #/# need v5.16 for /r

    my $num;
    while (my $f = pop @fields) {
        ($num) = $f =~ /(\d+)/;
        last if $num;
    }

    say "$ip $num";
}
```

The IP is still obtained from the first field, and cleaned up the same way as before.

Comment: Thank u for the advices. very useful.

Comment: @OdileAcotie  You are welcome.  I hope that the code works for you, too.  If something doesn't please let me know.

Comment: ok I see what is going on.you see, when i use the code with the portion of the file that i post it works because see between the last number that I want and the "?" there is no white space but in the original file there is space between them and for some line there is no "?" but "i" and in that case i want also the number before the "i".                                                * e  10.238.1.202                0 65103 65000 65112 ?
*|i206.112.193.64/26  10.6.76.242          2        100          0 65000 65533 i
*>i         10.6.76.240              2        100          0 65000 65533 i

Comment: @OdileAcotie  OK. That is very different, please be careful in the future when posting.  Seemingly small differences in formats may make a big difference. See the update to the answer.

Comment: 10.1.5.0/24 1
10.1.9.0/24 1
10.2.9.0/25 1 this is the output.$num returns 1 for all lines not the number i am expecting

Comment: @OdileAcotie  For a line `10.1.5.0/24 1 10.1.9.0/24 1 10.2.9.0/25 1` (from your last comment) I get `10.1.5.0/24 1` -- isn't that what you need?  The first (IP) and the last number.

Comment: i want for example: 10.1.5.0/24  65000 10.1.9.0/24 64000 i want the adresse and the number before "?" or "i"

Comment: @OdileAcotie  Oh, sorry -- I had left out parenthesis in `($num)` (used to have `s///` there instead).  Corrected, should be fine now.

Comment: @OdileAcotie  Great.  Let me know if some explanations would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are nothing particular to do, only to continue the line description with the number you want to capture:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $conf, '<', 'putty-wan.log') || die "Don't eat too much Montbéliard saussages\n";
open (my $output, '>', 'RouterNetwork.txt') || die ('Vous ne pouvez pas créer le fichier "RouterNetwork.txt"');

while( <$conf> ) { # the current line is stored in $_
    print $output "$1\t$2\n" if /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\/\d{1,2}).*\b(\d+)\?/;
}

close $output;
close $conf;
```

Note the word boundary before the number to be sure to obtain the whole number and not the last digit only.

The pattern can also be shorten to: `/([\d.]{7,15}\/\d\d?).*?(\d+)\?/`

Take care to not use old school programming style and look at perl current practises. *(use strict and warnings systematically)*

Note that with log files, a fields approach *(split the line by whitespaces)* is sometimes more handy.

Comment: Ok.it works with the portion of the file I post now with the whole file I am having a problem because the is the router description at the top of my file

Comment: @OdileAcotie:In this case edit the pattern to make it more precise (for example try to start it with `^\S*?` to be sure to catch the ip in the first field). As suggested, you can also try a field approach (split first and extract informations in a second time).